# SSIS OLE DB Command Output

Tags: sql, database, ssis, command, ole

I've searched through the related posts but cannot find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have an OLE DB Source that produces multiple rows (around 200) through a stored procedure.  I need to take 3 values in each row and pass them to an OLE DB Command that runs another stored procedure for each row.

What I need is to get the output of the second stored procedure.  I've read posts regarding using lookup, merge join, derived column but I still don't understand exactly how to put it all together.  My destination is an excel file.  Once I've obtained this output, I believe I can figure out how to merge the OLE DB Source results and the OLE DB Command results into one table.

One more thing, CREATING A TEMP TABLE ISN'T AN OPTION!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow the logic of what you're attempting to do. Do want specific columns passed to this sproc or rows? Can you pass it to and ADO Variable then execute the sql task? If you only need 3 values how do you determine which of the 200 rows are the ones to use?

Comment: Stored procedure X outputs 200 rows with columns labeled A, B, C, D, E and F.  Stored Procedure Y takes 3 parameters, an A, a B and a C and outputs columns labeled G, H, I, J and K.  I need to capture the table with columns G-K for each row Stored Procedure X produces.  What would I pass to a variable?  How do I map this to my destination file?

Comment: If you run procedure Y in an Execute SQL Task then you have to load the result into a variable of type object, then iterate over that variable row by row with a For Each container or by using script. If you run procedure Y in the source of a data flow and everything is just right, then you can use it as a source. So first try putting a dataflow inside your For Each loop. It would be really helpful if you described exactly what you've set up so far - i.e. have you got as far processing the result of the first SP inside a for each loop?

Comment: Thanks Electric.  So far I have a Data Flow consisting of an Ole DB Source which has Stored Procedure X.  Next in the pipeline is an Ole DB Command where I have Stored Procedure Y with a statement:  EXEC [dbo].[DoSomething] ?,?,? That runs for each row in SP X.  All of this is inside the Data Flow.  I don't have any for loops or for each loops.  The Ole DB Command automatically runs for each row in the OLE DB Source.

Comment: If I put Stored Procedure Y in an Execute SQL Task, how do I pass it the parameters from Stored Procedure X?  Same way as using an OLE DB Command, with ?'s...?